# Number of unit roots in a group verifying a special property

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group verifying that all subgroups are generated by kth powers of G elements for some k.

My question : Is there a finite number of pth roots for the neutral ?

I tried to study the fibers of some morphisms and to find a contradiction supposing that there are an infinite number of these roots but I didn’t found anything interesting.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If I understand you correctly the complicated sounding condition involving subgroups is automatically satisfied for groups that have the much simpler condition that every element is itself a $k$'th power for some $k$.

Now look at $SO(3)$, the group of rotations of the sphere. Obviously every rotation is the $k$'th power of the rotation around the same axis but around only $1/k$'th of the angle and moreover for every axis the rotation around that axis over an angle of $2\pi/p$ is a $p$'th root of unity.

Looking at a sphere it is easy to see that there are infinitely many of those.

So the group of rotations of the sphere is a counterexample.

Comment: I was meaning that for any subgroup H, there exist a k for which H is generated by all kth powers of G elements.

Comment: ALL $k$'th powers. Hmmm that greatly reduces the number of possible groups. Cyclic groups are an example but are there any others?

Comment: Of course all cyclic group and &\mathbb{Z}& satisfy the property but I cannot prove it is the only ones.

Comment: You should ask that as a seperate question I think: are there any examples of groups with this property, except the cyclic (including infinite cyclic) ones?